# quantity input box on featured products -Opencart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

can you help for  quantity input box on featured products , opencart 2.3.0.2

```
<input type="text" size="3" id="quantity-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" name="quantity" value="1" placeholder="1" class="form-control my-form-control input-lg qty-input radius-none pull-left" />
```

this code will show input box and default 1 and it adds 1 products to cart but I need any numbers to be added to cart.

Comment: <input type="text" size="3" id="quantity-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" name="quantity" value="1" placeholder="1" class="form-control my-form-control input-lg qty-input radius-none pull-left" />

Answer (score 0):

You should change the value attribute. Like `value="<?php echo $needed_quantity; ?>"`

Or delete value attribute but than you need to check if user set the quantity (check if empty) and inform user that he must set the quantity manually

Comment: its not working , how to get quantity on featured.tpl??

Comment: 1) find featured controller (catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php) and add needed quantity to `$data` array like this: `$data['quantity'] = 5;` (or any other number you want)

2) and then use $quantity variable in template: `value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>"`

Comment: if insert this value , displays notice  <b>Notice</b> on line <b>85</b> , any quick solutions?

Comment: copy all notice here